# Creating Status Bars Inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create two status bars based on number of likes and dislikes.  I want to resize the status bars for each cell.  I am having trouble resizing the bars though.  I have two ideas in mind on how to resize these bars.

1. I created UIViews and colored them red and green. I want to resize them, but I am unsure how to do this because Xcode doesn't allow me to access the size parameters.

   ```
   cell.PositiveBar.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
   ```

[image]

How can I have these status bars that change based on the likes and dislikes, looking for on a way to do this.

Comment: Your question is too broad and have a lack of information, we don't know do you using custom table view cell or default, is it problem in only width on in drawing this, so give us full info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have custom cell class, you need to add variables and connect them with views.
In cellForRow method you need to access to the Cell and config view's width, for that you can use layer or view, for example to change cell's status bar width:

```
- (void)setSellStatusBarByLikes:(NSInteger)likes
{
    CGRect newFrame = self.positiveBar.frame;

    // here you calculate width from likes count with your formula
    newFrame.size.width = likes * dt;
    [self.positiveBar setFrame:newFrame];
}
```

and for animation you need to wrap your setFrame method

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.1f animations:^{
  [self.positiveBar setFrame:newFrame];
}];
```

After this you can call this method from cellForRowClass

```
// In table view class
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HomeCell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [_p_leftTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [cell setSellStatusBarByLikes:10];


    return cell;
}
```

***EDIT***
So you can do your custom class in storyboard, or upgrade UITAbleViewCell class with programatically added status bars. All next steps depends on your method.
When you declare variable inside your CustomTableViewCell as IBoutlet (if you do it through storyboard) or simple @property, it's already a part of CustomTableViewCell, then you can use it as self.something.

If you make this programmatically in default cell, then you just need to recreate your status bar views in cellForRow method.

Comment: What is the dt variable, just curious?

Comment: I declared PositiveBar as a property in a custom UITableViewCell Class, How would I allow the positivebar be part of self?

Comment: dt it's can be your value, on which need to multiply your likes for view to be visible. In fact it can depends of your cells size, for example likes = 1, dt = 0.1f, and you will have width of 0.1, if dt = 10f, you width of frame with 1 like will 10 etc. 
You need to create your view inside storyboard or programmatically and call this "setSellStatusBarByLikes" from cellForRow method